# XPath evaluation in JAXB binding file results in empty target node

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I try to change xsd element name via external jaxb binding file but for some reason global binding does not work and Xpath can't find the element

Schema I want to change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.sitels.ru/FORIS/IL/DomainModel" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.sitels.ru/FORIS/IL/DomainModel">
  <xs:complexType name="BaseDictionary">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Code" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DateFrom" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DateTo" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Id" nillable="true" type="tns:UniqueIdentifier"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="BaseDictionary" nillable="true" type="tns:BaseDictionary"/>
  <xs:complexType name="UniqueIdentifier">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="EntityId" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ForisId" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="UniqueIdentifier" nillable="true" type="tns:UniqueIdentifier"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Jaxb binding file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
               xs:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
               jaxb:version="2.1">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="DomainModel.xsd" node="//xs:schema//xs:element[@name='BaseDictionary']">
        <jaxb:class name="DomainBaseDictionary" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I get  XPath evaluation of "//xs:schema//xs:element[@name='BaseDictionary']" results in empty target node when trying to compile

Comment: I think you are trying to use JAXB to read the XSD, edit the name attribute in one of the element declarations and then serialize the modified XSD.
 
Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

The xs: namespace prefix referes to different namespaces in the two documents.
In your xsd you have:

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

In your binding file you have:

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
```

So xs:schema != xs:schema. Either fix the namespaces, or write the xpath namespace neutral ( `//*[local-name() = 'schema']/*[local-name()='element' and @name='BaseDirectory']`)