# Dealing with duplicate classes with multiple maven-jaxb2-plugin executions using different schemas with the same base schema

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm currently using maven-jaxb2-plugin v0.13.3.

The plugin config has multiple executions, each processing wsdl files.  Several of them are completely independent, but several are simply different wsdls in the same enterprise, with schemas that import a common base schema.

Note that I cannot change the wsdls or the schemas.

The original code was using "forceRegenerate" set to true, along with all of them writing to the same target directory.  This works fine with a command-line build, but as many people know by now, this causes an infinite build loop in Eclipse.

I'm working through the steps to fully resolve this.  The easy steps are setting "forceRegenerate" to false and adding a suffix directory to the "generateDirectory" directory for each execution to make them unique.  I then have to change the Eclipse project properties to remove the original source directory for the common place they were all writing to, and replace that with a single ref for each of the now unique source directories.

Up to now, this would work fine if all the executions referenced fully independent schemas.

If two or more of these executions specify a wsdl that has schemas that reference a common base schema, which is the case here, I get duplicate class errors at build time.

If it helps, here is some sample code from the pom that has been somewhat elided:

```
<execution>
  <id>unifiedServices</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>generate</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <specVersion>2.2</specVersion>
    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schemas/csi_UnifiedServices_240.0_schema</schemaDirectory>
    <schemaIncludes>
      <include>*.wsdl</include>
    </schemaIncludes>
    <generateDirectory>target/generated-sources/jaxb/us</generateDirectory>
    <forceRegenerate>false</forceRegenerate>
  </configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
  <id>iuclp</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>generate</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <specVersion>2.2</specVersion>
    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schemas/csi_OrderAndSubscriptionManagementMobility</schemaDirectory>
    <schemaIncludes>
      <include>*.wsdl</include>
    </schemaIncludes>
    <generateDirectory>target/generated-sources/jaxb/osmm</generateDirectory>
    <forceRegenerate>false</forceRegenerate>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

I've seen many postings that talk about variations of this, many of which refer to older versions of the plugin.

What are some practical solutions to this that still fulfill my constraints (can't modify the wsdl/schema)?

**Update**:

I am proceeding to implement the bindings file, as suggested in the first answer.  It's not quite working, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is the configuration block of the first execution (I've only changed one execution block, once I determine it's generating reasonable code, I'll work on the other execution blocks, and then change the references in the code).

```
<configuration>
    <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/bindings</bindingDirectory>
    <bindingIncludes>
        <bindingInclude>unifiedservices.xjb</bindingInclude>
    </bindingIncludes>
  <specVersion>2.2</specVersion>
  <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schemas/csi_UnifiedServices_240.0_schema</schemaDirectory>
  <schemaIncludes>
    <include>*.wsdl</include>
  </schemaIncludes>
  <generateDirectory>target/generated-sources/jaxb/us</generateDirectory>
  <forceRegenerate>false</forceRegenerate>
</configuration>
```

This is the slightly elided bindings file (unifiedservices.xjb):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    jxb:version="2.0">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://.../Namespaces/UnifiedServices/Types/Public/CommonDataModel.xsd"
                  node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <nameXmlTransform>
                <typeName suffix="us"/>
            </nameXmlTransform>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

This is the header of the slightly elided "CommonDataModel.xsd":

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
 xmlns='http://.../Namespaces/UnifiedServices/Types/Public/CommonDataModel.xsd'
 targetNamespace='http://.../Namespaces/UnifiedServices/Types/Public/CommonDataModel.xsd'
 elementFormDefault='qualified'
 version='240.0.03'>
```

When I run this build, I get this as the first error:

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/.../src/main/resources/bindings/unifiedservices.xjb{8,37}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: "http://.../Namespaces/UnifiedServices/Types/Public/CommonDataModel.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for "file:/C:/.../src/main/resources/schemas/csi_UnifiedServices_240.0_schema/CommonDataModel.xsd"?
```

**Update**:

I updated the bindings file so that "schemaLocation" is just a relative path to the schema file in question, but now I just get a different error.

This is my new bindings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    jxb:version="2.0">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/csi_UnifiedServices_240.0_schema/CommonDataModel.xsd"
                  node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <nameXmlTransform>
                <typeName suffix="us"/>
            </nameXmlTransform>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

When I build with this, I get:

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/C:/.../src/main/resources/bindings/unifiedservices.xjb{8,37}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: XPath evaluation of "/xs:schema" results in empty target node
```

This is the somewhat elided header of the "CommonDataModel.xsd" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- ... -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
 xmlns='http://.../Namespaces/UnifiedServices/Types/Public/CommonDataModel.xsd'
 targetNamespace='http://.../Namespaces/UnifiedServices/Types/Public/CommonDataModel.xsd'
 elementFormDefault='qualified'
 version='240.0.03'>
```

I had to ask myself whether that relative path is correct.  I would think if it was wrong, I would get a more specific error message. For a little confirmation, I ran SysInternals ProcessMonitor, watching for "CommonDataModel.xsd", and they were all to that same file, and all were successful.

**Update**:

I think I found a possible cause for that last problem. The following pointed out an issue: [XPath evaluation in JAXB binding file results in empty target node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57883855/xpath-evaluation-in-jaxb-binding-file-results-in-empty-target-node) .

So, I made sure that the two "xs" namespaces were identical.  This got rid of the xjc errors.  However, it also didn't appear to do anything.

My current binding file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    jxb:version="2.0">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../schemas/csi_UnifiedServices_240.0_schema/CommonDataModel.xsd"
                  node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings>
            <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
                <jxb:typeName suffix="us"/>
            </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

When I run the build, I see blocks of output lines like this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.3:generate (unifiedServices) @ UnifiedAccountMs ---
[INFO] Sources are not up-to-date, XJC will be executed.
[INFO] Episode file [C:\...\target\generated-sources\jaxb\us\META-INF\sun-jaxb.episode] was augmented with if-exists="true" attributes.
```

That looks fine, but it doesn't tell me anything.  When it finally does the compile, I get errors like this:

```
[ERROR] /C:/.../target/generated-sources/jaxb/us/com/cingular/csi/csi/namespaces/unifiedservices/infrastructurecommon/types/_public/messageheader/ObjectFactory.java:[32,8] duplicate class: com.cingular.csi.csi.namespaces.unifiedservices.infrastructurecommon.types._public.messageheader.ObjectFactory
```

And when I searched for that fqcn, I did indeed find multiple occurrences of it (the elided portions are identical):

```
./target/generated-sources/jaxb/ausn/com/.../namespaces/unifiedservices/infrastructurecommon/types/_public/messageheader/ObjectFactory.java
./target/generated-sources/jaxb/us/com/.../namespaces/unifiedservices/infrastructurecommon/types/_public/messageheader/ObjectFactory.java
```

I may be misunderstanding what the "typeName" transformation is supposed to do, but it doesn't seem like it changed anything.  In any case, I have a feeling that appending a suffix to the class name isn't exactly what I want.  I think changing the package name is more appropriate, but I can't even get the typename transformation to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to add a separate binding file (*.xjb) to each execution in order to generate specific classes (and avoiding name clash).

```
<configuration>
  <bindingDirectory>src/main/bindings</bindingDirectory>
  <bindingIncludes>
    <include>unifiedServices.xjb</include>
  </bindingIncludes>
```

See the [XJC documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) , but it is for instance possible to add a suffix to all class names:

```
<schemaBindings>
  <nameXmlTransform>
    <typeName suffix="_SuffixA"/>
  </nameXmlTransform>
</schemaBindings>
```

Doing so, if the same "Foo" type of namespace "company.com" is part of a same common schema imported by several wsdl, you could end up with distinct classes:

- com.company.Foo_SuffixA (generated in "unifiedServices")
- com.company.Foo_SuffixB (generated in "iuclp")

Comment: I get the basic idea, but it's not at all obvious what needs to be filled in at various points here.  I'll update the posting with what I've tried so far.

Comment: Your schema location 'jxb:bindings schemaLocation="http...' (in the xjb file) is wrong, it has to be a **relative** path (based on the binding fille location). For instance: schemaLocation="../../schemas/my-schema.xsd'.
Full example: https://gist.github.com/nazartm/5014497

Comment: Ok. I changed that, but now it's saying "XPath evaluation of "/xs:schema" results in empty target node". I'll update with what I did.

Comment: The namespace for xs is not the same in your xjb as in the xsd: 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
vs
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
=> use the one of the xsd in the xjb file !

Comment: Thanks, I had actually noticed that. I changed them to match in the last update. The process is now basically working, although I discovered that the ObjectFactory class is not covered by the mapping. I'm handling that with an antrun plugin to delete the duplicate ones, which I got from another posting on this same subject. I also noticed some curious discrepancies in the supposedly duplicate classes handled by the mapping. the CODE was truly identical, but I noticed some odd differences in the generated comments showing the schema they were derived from. I have to do more analysis there.

Comment: If you do not like to work with suffix, there is also a more radical solution: generate each execution in a distinct package:
<configuration>
        <packageName>com.example.iuclp</packageName>
 </configuration>

Comment: It's actually '<jxb:package name="..."/>', but I get it. I'm exploring this option. I don't know that this is "more radical". In fact, changing the package results in fewer changes to the user code and appending a suffix to the type name.